# How to make every javascript variable exclusive inside an asp.net core foreach?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've the following script tag inside a foreach in my razor page:

```
setInterval(function updatetime() {
    let currentDateTime = new Date(Date.now());
    $('#time').html(currentDateTime)
},1000);

const current = new Date(Date.now());
const endtime = new Date('2022-08-31T16:45:22');
$('#endtime').html(endtime);

const i = setInterval(function () { myFunction(); }, 60000);

function myFunction() {
    current = new Date(Date.now());
    if (new Date(current) > new Date(endtime)) {
        doing();
    }
```

Only the first element of the foreach list works properly but the others don't. here's the rendered code for 2 of those elements: https://pastebin.com/8b1Kj8MA

Is it possible to make each script tag private and not accessible from outside the foreach?

Comment: Why are you constructing new date objects out of date objects inside `myFunction`?

Comment: @Lain That's how i saw it on a tutorial page, It's working nonetheless.

Comment: You are overriding a `const` value `current`.

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz The code is working perfectly fine, i just need a way to stop variables from interfering with other (foreach) variables

Comment: What do you mean `variables interfering with other variables`? The code you provided always updates the same HTML elements - `#time` and `#endtime`

Comment: Remember that HTML ids should be unique for elements. You should now have multiple HTML elements with the same ID

Comment: @TomaszStaszkiewicz i can make HTML elements ids unique by doing something like: "#id-@item.id" but I can't do the same thing for variables names inside a script tag.

Comment: @Mohamed Yousef Khairlden: **Is it possible to make each script tag private and not accessible from outside the foreach?** You could wrap those in an [anonymous function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/). As long as you do not use globals the variables are bound to the function scope. But I think this is a xy-problem.